# proxychains bower fails DNS lookup

Tags: linux, proxy, dns, bower

For reasons beyond my comprehension and control, the corporation that I'm working for puts a proxy between all web traffic on its corporate network. This means that HTTPS leaf signitures are never correct. To get around this, I have configured a proxy at home that allows me to use proxychains. Browsing the web works pretty well, but I can't get 'proxychains bower install' to work. I've changed the DNS in /lib/usr/proxychains3/proxyresolv to '8.8.8.8' (google's DNS)

Here's what I've tried:

```
# bower install
bower UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE      Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-animate failed: unable to verify the first certificate

# proxychains bower install
|DNS-request| bower.herokuapp.com 
|DNS-request| bower.herokuapp.com 
|DNS-request| bower.herokuapp.com 
|DNS-request| bower.herokuapp.com 
|DNS-response|: bower.herokuapp.com does not exist
bower: src/unix/getaddrinfo.c:91: uv__getaddrinfo_translate_error: Assertion `!"unknown EAI_* error code"' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

# . /usr/lib/proxychains3/proxyresolv bower.herokuapp.com
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-8.8.8.8:53-<><>-OK
50.17.253.207
```

Why does the DNS lookup fail with the proxychains cmd, but pass with the proxyresolv? Is there anyway to fix it? Or am I looking at filing a bug?

Or am I just barking up the wrong tree and should add a proxy my .bowerrc?

Comment: I'm getting a similar issue, but with `npm install`. Did you figure this out yet?

Comment: I did not figure this problem out, I figured another way to get to the internet at large instead.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I solved it by making a change in `/etc/proxychains.conf`. I commented the line `strict_chain` and uncommented the line `dynamic_chain`. Now this works for me.

This is the error message I had before:

```
|DNS-response|: <domain> does not exist
xmrigMiner: src/unix/getaddrinfo.c:91: uv__getaddrinfo_translate_error: Assertion `!"unknown EAI_* error code"' failed.
Aborted
```